# Handling a single pod with multiple container

Tags: kubernetes, endpoint, kubernetes-pod

I have a requirement to convert a multipod setup to a single pod with multiple container. I had pod x running x microservice and pod y running y microservice with below rest endpoint.

- `http://x:8080/{context path-x}/endpoint`
- `http://y:8080/{context path-y}/endpoint`

I want to have pod z with x and y microservice with container x exposed on 8080 port and y on 8081 within same pod. I am able to achieve these with multi-container pod.

My problem is now the URL are changed

- `http://z:8080/{context path-x}/endpoint`
- `http://z:8081/{context path-y}/endpoint`

I am looking for way in which I can hit endpoints without the change is URL or minimum hit with below URLs

- `http://x:8080/{context path-x}/endpoint`
- `http://y:8081/{context path-y}/endpoint`

My real project requirement has 5 container on single pods and has 100s of endpoints exposed

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you use different Services?

Comment: If you want 0 change in url, then you need 2 services named x & y. x exposes 8080 port and y exposes 8081 port. did you get it?

Comment: Thank you for the response . @Shudipta Sharma. I think this solution works for us. I have created 2 services now to hit 8080 and 8081 and old url works with changing the port numbers.

Comment: Great that you have solved it. Please provide the answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K8s services are the way to expose your application. Since you have two applications and want to run them as two different containers inside a single Pod and you want minimum changes in your application API URL, then simply create create two different Services having your trageted ports. Thus you need 0 changes in your application's APP url.

In K8s cluster, you can use simply the name of the service name as the host name from the same namespace. You can see [FQDN (fully qualified domain name) convention for a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

Hence, you can create two Services with name `x` and `y`, where `x` have the port 8080 and `y` have the port 8081. Thus you can use the same urls as before.

> NOTE: There may exist different ways to achieve one's goal(s) but may arise different issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I addressed my problem:

Application Deployment File (x and y containers on deployment z)

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: z
spec:
  replicas: 1
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: z
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        version: v1.0
      labels:
        component: z
        occloud.oracle.com/open-network-policy: allow
      name: z
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: x
          image:x:dev
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
        - name: y
          image: y:dev
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: x
  annotations:
    version: v1.0
spec:
  selector:
    component: z
  ports:
     - name: x
       port: 8080
       targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP           
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: y
  annotations:
    version: v1.0
spec:
  selector:
    component: z
  ports:
     - name: y
       port: 8080
       targetPort: 8081
  type: ClusterIP
```

http://x:8080/{context path-x}/endpoint
http://y:8080/{context path-y}/endpoint